# How are Google maps API limits calculated?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am trying to build an Android application that relies on Google Maps for the mapping functionality. Google Maps API FAQ mentions that the maximum number of requests are 25000 map loads per day for each service.

As i have just one key for development and am hoping that the app will be used by at least a few hundred people i want to make sure that i understand the limits correctly.

Is the maximum limit associated with my key and hence the sum of all request made by all applications or is it for each app on every independent device.

Comment: Was my answer an answer to your question? If so, please accept/upvote it. It is the least you could do when somebody tries to help you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it is for all applications that use your key combined, but per Google service:
[FAQ Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits)

So if you have three apps that all have 200 users that use the apps two times a day, then it would be 2*200*3 = 1200 map loads per day on your API key. And this is the value that should not exceed the maximum number of map loads [set by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits).